# What do I miss in my code that it fails on "adv_acc_search_table" variable? The actual table does not have <tr> tag elements

Tags: python, if-statement, selenium-webdriver, click, tr

I am trying to use ***if*** statement to find and click any `tr` tag elements in a table and if its not available then continue with ***else***.
Here is my code below and screenshot of HTML for the table which has `tr` tags.
I want to run this code with no `tr` tag elements in a table but it fails.

What do I miss? Any suggestions.

```
adv_acc_search_table = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="standard_table_body"]>table tr')))
try:                               
    for account in adv_acc_search_table:
        if account > 0:
            account.click()
            break
        else:
            print("No Accounts to select")
            wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[id="advanced_account_search_window_window_title"] img'))).click()
            APA = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'MLADAT'))))
            APA.select_by_index(0)                                  
except:
    TimeoutException
```

[image]

HTML

Comment: The execption type should be immediately after `except`, e.g. `except TimeoutException: code to run when the exception occurs`

Comment: `else:` needs to be indented one level less. It will then be executed if you never `break` out of the loop.

Comment: ```except``` corrected

Comment: ```else:``` indented as advised but still it does not iterate ```else``` statement codes

Comment: What is the value of `adv_acc_search_table`?

Comment: `if account > 0:` doesn't make sense. If `account` is a number, how could `account.click()` work?

Comment: That's probably getting an error, but you're hiding that with `except:`. Don't hide errors when you're debugging.

Comment: Maybe you meant `if len(adv_acc_search_table) > 0:` before the loop?

Comment: Thanks for notes @Barmar. Your comments make a sense. Probably I need to use ```len(account)```. I will try it now. The value for `adv_acc_search_table` is different type of accounts for customer with several columns which I can click as row.

Comment: The main purpose is `click()` on `<tr>` tag if its available in the table otherwise continue with `else`.

Comment: Looks like adv_acc_search_table holds List<WebElement> as wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located) returns the same. Later you are iterating using for-each loop for each WebElement in it. We can't compare WebElement with 0. When you tried to compare with 0, it returned false, hence else block will be executed by default here..